# Android inline-block elements unrecognized character issue

Tags: android, css, mobile, webkit

Has anyone come across a problem with the Android browser where rectangular unrecognized character glyphs are shown between or next to inline-block elements? If this is a known issue, is there an easy workaround?

Tested on generic 2.3 emulator and HTC 2.3 browsers so far. 2.1 does not show the problem.

The page has a UTF-8 charset.

Comment: There's a bug report for this issue here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15067

Comment: Thanks, I also added it to Scott Jehl's list of device bugs: https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by removing `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility` which I had on the `html` element.

Comment: I wasted over an hour on this...I'll never get it back!

Comment: I can confirm having on the body -> text-rendering: optimizeLegibility also causes rendering issues of encoded characters (only when using the @import rule). In my case glyphicons from bootstrap.css v3.0.3 or other custom icons were not rendering. (Android Browser on Nexus 4 - 4.0.3)