# Android browser not handling new line (ASCII x0A) character correctly

Tags: android, css, character-encoding, newline, whitespace

Android's browser is displaying "box" characters (like []) wherever there is a new line (ASCII x0A) character in the source HTML.

The browser should treat / render new line characters as whitespace.  This issue doesn't appear on any desktop browsers or iOS Safari.

We have isolated the culprit to one of our CSS files but can't narrow down the offending code any further.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  We are baffled.  We have looked into character encoding issues and the font-family and changing those didn't resolve the issue.

Screenshot: http://haxway.com/mjm.jpeg
HTML: http://haxway.com/mjm.html
CSS: http://www.marijuana.com/styles/hathwaymobile/styles.css

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is a known bug with the Android browser (2.2 only if I remember right - will expand when I get a chance).

Comment: Duct-tape fix is to just replace all of the LF with <br /> or some equivalent of that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android inline-block elements unrecognized character issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400047/android-inline-block-elements-unrecognized-character-issue)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `text-rendering: optimizelegibility` is broken on Android 2.2 and 2.3.

See this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15067

> This HTML:
>
> ```
> <p style="text-rendering:optimizelegibility">
> Webkit.
> Android.
> Oh no.
> ```
>
> is rendered with boxes where the newlines are.
>
> Happens in 2.2 and 2.3. Does not happen in 1.6.

A jsfiddle illustrating this bug: http://jsfiddle.net/therefromhere/huUcE/2/